# setting editing within a UISegment Control

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am writing a universal app using both UISplitViewController and a UISegmentedControl. Each controller in the UISegmentedControl allows editing. It appears that the editing state of the controllers must be re-established when a segment becomes the current segment. My problem is strange animations that result from `[vc setEditing:YES animation:NO]`.  Can someone suggest how I might avoid this? Thank you.

```
- (void)segmentChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{ 
    UIViewController *vc = [self viewControllerForSegmentIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];

    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:vc duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
        [vc setEditing:YES animated:NO];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        self.currentViewController = vc;
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid inappropriate animations, I completed the preparation preparation for display of the Controller with setEditing and viewWillAppear.

```
   [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:vc duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
        [vc setEditing:YES animated:NO];
        [vc viewWillAppear:NO]; 
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        self.currentViewController = vc;
    }];
```